# How to fix zlib error in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

When I write this command :

```
gem install bundler && bundle install --without test
```

the output is :

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

so, obviously I tried to install `zlib1g-dev` and `libssl-dev` but it was already installed on my system,

```
#sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 180 not upgraded.
```

any idea ?
my OS info :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I installed this version of ruby :

```
# ruby -v
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: How have you installed Ruby? I assume this is not the Ruby from the Ubuntu packages?

Comment: Again, **how** have you installed Ruby? Have you compiled it yourself, using rbenv, RVM, anything else? It seems that zlib was not available during compilation of your Ruby and is thus not supported by your Ruby. You probably need to re-compile it with zlib support.

Comment: I done this : sudo apt-get install ruby-full

Comment: That would have given you a Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu Trusty. Find how you actually installed your current Ruby and then (probably) reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you, My problem solved via this:

```
aptitude purge ruby
```

I hope you will find this command useful.